# Why does this <audio> example fail on some browsers?

Tags: html

Why does this  example http://chrisjj.drivehq.com/test.htm

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

(from http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) fail on Firefox 16 and IE9?

It succeeds on Chrome V24.

UPDATE:

```
<!doctype html>  
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="application/x-msdownload">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

works on IE9, but (despite http://web-sniffer.net/ shows "Content-Type: application/x-msdownload") not on FF.

Comment: Don't rely on w3schools, they are very old and not good, if you want to check the status of a feature for a browser, use caniuse.com Refer to this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio both browsers do support, you may be missing the proper codec for them.

Comment: where is your doctype? where is all the content of the page?

Comment: What kind of OGG is it? Firefox only supports OGG vorbis.

Comment: Quirks mode for each browser will be quirky in a different quirky way. Your test is not a valid html page.

Comment: Following your edit: why are you expecting `application/x-msdownload` to be an audio format supported by Firefox?  You have to fix the server to send as `content-type: audio/ogg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox, because the `content-type` header of the server's HTTP response for `horse.ogg` is `application/x-msdownload` instead of `audio/ogg`.

In IE9, because the page is not a well formed HTML document with a `DOCTYPE`, `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` elements. Not being a proper HTML document will trigger quirks mode.

Comment: both are actually not respecting the audio tag because of a lack of doctype to begin with...the first part should be unnecessary for firefox 16...

Comment: Thanks Robert. doctype fixes the IE9 case, but kluge to the HTML type= does not fix the FF case. Question updated.

Comment: @IlanBiala Actually, Firefox copes just fine with the `<audio>` tag even when the page is so broken, [try it](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/html5/audio/test.html).

Comment: @ChrisJJ Nothing you put in the markup will fix it in Firefox, it's the server you have to fix to send the correct content type

Comment: Thanks Robert. Reporting to DriveHQ now.

Comment: Sorry I read your first part wrong @robertc, you are correct in stating that the content type should be audio/ogg, I don't know why I misinterpreted that.

Comment: @IlanBiala No worries, you might have read a slightly garbled earlier edit, I changed it a few times within a minute of posting.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If IE 9 isn't accepting everything you give it that it should, you may have to force it to accept the HTML5 doctype and its corresponding features, and from the looks of your page, you are missing a doctype, which means you haven't even done that yet.